# WPF C# - How Can I Dynamically Add ComboBoxItems?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, combobox

I am currently trying to dynamically add ComboBoxItems to a ComboBox that was also created dynamically. I get an error saying that the ComboBox name does not exist.

Anyone know how I would be able to get around this? Any help is appreciated.

```
YearGroupRegistersRightSide.Children.Add(new ComboBox { Name = "DynamicCombobox3", SelectedIndex = 0 });

DynamicCombobox3.Children.Add(new ComboBoxItem{Name="Item One", Content="<--- Select --->>"});
```

Comment: I would argue that in WPF you should do this via databinding (MVVM). The combobox should be instantiated using a template/itemtemplate/contentpresenter and the items should be assigned through a binding as well. If you add more info on what the dynamic combobox is based on one could give a more appropriate answer

Comment: Take a look at [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview). If you're going to dynamically add items to a ComboBox, you should set or bind its ItemsSource property to a collection of item objects (e.g. strings) and use an appropriate DataTemplate (or set DisplayMemberPath) for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combobox doesn't have a Children property.
I suggest you new up your combo first then you can keep a reference to it easily.
Like:

```
ComboBox DynamicCombobox3 = new ComboBox { Name = "DynamicCombobox3", SelectedIndex = 0 };
YearGroupRegistersRightSide.Children.Add(DynamicCombobox3);

DynamicCombobox3.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Name = "Item One" });
```

Comment: Sure, he should learn mvvm. Maybe use templating to create the combo and probably bind the itemssource to a resource or collection. Or maybe he should be building XAML as xml instead and using xamlreader.parse. Impossible to tell from the code given.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `ComboBox` is not getting instantiated, try changing the 1st line to the following:

```
ComboBox DynamicCombobox3 = new ComboBox() { Name = "DynamicCombobox3", SelectedIndex = 0 };
```

Maybe you are missing the round brackets which call the constructor of `ComboBox`.

Comment: It's of course instantiated, just not assigned to a variable named DynamicCombobox3.